# Is there a way to hide a closing container in a template?

Tags: angular

I'm optionally hiding some child/grandchild DOM elements using *ngIf, but the parent and grandparent elements have some formatting that remains even with the child/grandchildren removed from the DOM (the borders still remain). Is there a way that I can hide the parent/grandparent elements to remove the formatting altogether when the children/grandchildren are removed?

```
  <div class="member-body" *ngFor="let key of memberKeys">
    <div class="member-section">
      <div class="member-section-header">

<!-- THE *ngIf BELOW IS WHERE I REMOVE CHILDREN/GRANDCHILDREN THAT SHOULD BE HIDDEN . . . 
BUT WHEN THE *ngIf IS TRIGGERED I WANT TO ALSO REMOVE THE "member-body" 
and "member-section" ELEMENTS ABOVE -->

        <ng-container  *ngIf="!member[key].catText.hidden">
          <label class="member-section-label">{{member[key].someStuff}}&nbsp;</label>
          <div [ngClass]="'member-section-body'">
            <app-sub-enroll-form ></app-sub-enroll-form>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why not to put the `*ngIf` at the parent/grandparent?

Comment: Apply `*ngFor` on an outer `ng-container` and `*ngIf` on the `member-body` div.

Comment: Uggh! Obviously! . . . Tks @ConnorsFan & @dcg!